# ContextMenu in Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

So I've been looking around and searching Google, but I just can't find the answer. I'm trying to set my Textbox's context menu to a context menu, not a context menu strip. In the properties window, it doesn't allow me to set the context menu, just the context menu strip. Can anyone show me how to set a context menu to my textbox? I know this answer might be somewhere already, but I just can't find it.

Comment: Please show what you have tried first. If you are stuck we can help you.

Comment: The property is simply hidden.  Cut the mouse umbilical cord and write code.  Assign the ContextMenu property in your Sub New constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first create a ContextMenu. Then do this

```
private void InitializeAltContextMenu()
{
    mnuContextDefault = new ContextMenu();
    mnuContextDefault = this.TextBox1.ContextMenu;

    mnuItmAltMenuTest = new MenuItem();
    mnuItmAltMenuTest.Index = -1;
    mnuItmAltMenuTest.Text = "Test Menu Item";
    mnuItmAltMenuTest.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.mnuItmAltMenuTest_Click);

    mnuContextAlt = new ContextMenu();
    mnuContextAlt.MenuItems.Add(mnuItmAltMenuTest);
}
private void TextBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            if ((Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control))
            {
                this.TextBox1.ContextMenu = mnuContextAlt;
                TextBox1.ContextMenu.Show(TextBox1, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
            }
            else
            {
                this.TextBox1.ContextMenu = mnuContextDefault;
            }
        }
    }
```

**VB.NET CODE UPDATE**

```
Private Sub InitializeAltContextMenu()
    mnuContextDefault = New ContextMenu()
    mnuContextDefault = Me.TextBox1.ContextMenu

    mnuItmAltMenuTest = New MenuItem()
    mnuItmAltMenuTest.Index = -1
    mnuItmAltMenuTest.Text = "Test Menu Item"
    mnuItmAltMenuTest.Click += New System.EventHandler(Me.mnuItmAltMenuTest_Click)

    mnuContextAlt = New ContextMenu()
    mnuContextAlt.MenuItems.Add(mnuItmAltMenuTest)
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then
        If (Control.ModifierKeys = Keys.Control) Then
            Me.TextBox1.ContextMenu = mnuContextAlt
            TextBox1.ContextMenu.Show(TextBox1, New Point(e.X, e.Y))
        Else
            Me.TextBox1.ContextMenu = mnuContextDefault
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please don't feed these types of questions. The OP failed to show what they have done and where they are stuck. In the long wrong it doesn't help people by just throwing code out, that's not learning. Also it helps promote debugging which is crucial.

Comment: You are correct, though we should not stop helping them.

Comment: One more thing, could you please explain to OP where this goes exactly, what it does and transform it to VB which is what the OP tagged.

Comment: I didn't say to stop, there's a difference, **big difference**.

Comment: Also when the user selects an item what happens? I'm not seeing any methods of such unless I am overlooking it.

Comment: Hi Hemal, I'm actually looking for an answer in Visual Basic, but I see what your doing, and Codexer, I didn't think this would require code, I don't even know where to start, because everywhere I've looked on google doesn't show me where to start, sorry.

Comment: For VB, the code syntax changes, logic is same. And you will achieve what you asked. See VB Code in update

Comment: Also, try to more specific with what you have tried to get exact answer fast and for sure. You could have stated about VB.NET in your question with your tried code.